# Merge sort not sorting self created array class c++

Tags: c++, mergesort

my merge sort method dont work how i want to, ive created Array Class with some custom methods and tried to create proper components to merge sort work. 
result is that the returned table is filled with zeros and random numbers and it is being filled till memory is full.  Please if You could give me some tips to waht i should pay attention to fix it.

also full Array Class if You want to look at it here : 
https://codeshare.io/5Xnk9Y

thanks in advance for any help.

```
Array Array::merge(Array left, Array right, Array mergedArray)
{   
    int i,j,k,nL,nR;
    i=j=k=0;
    nL = left.GetNumberOfElements();
    nR = right.GetNumberOfElements();
    while(i < nL && j < nR)
    {
        if (left.GetElementWithIndex(i) <= right.GetElementWithIndex(j))
        {   
            mergedArray.SetElementWithIndex(k, left.GetElementWithIndex(i));
            i++;
            k++;
        }else 
        {
            mergedArray.SetElementWithIndex(k, right.GetElementWithIndex(j));
            k++;
            j++;
        }       
    }
    while (i < nL){
        mergedArray.SetElementWithIndex(k,left.GetElementWithIndex(i));

        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < nR){
        mergedArray.SetElementWithIndex(k, right.GetElementWithIndex(j));
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    return mergedArray;
}

Array Array::splitArrayForMergeSort(Array splitedArray)
{
    int length;
    length = splitedArray.GetNumberOfElements();
    if(length < 2) return splitedArray;

    int middle;


    if(length %2 == 1) middle = (length-1)/2;
    else middle = length/2;


    Array left;
    Array right;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < middle ; i++){
        left.AddElement(splitedArray[i]);
    }
    for (int i = middle ; i < length ; i++){
        right.AddElement(splitedArray[i]);
    }

    splitArrayForMergeSort(left);
    splitArrayForMergeSort(right);
    merge(left, right, splitedArray);
}

void Array::MergeSort()
{
    Array arr;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfElements ; i++){
        arr.AddElement(array[i]);
    }   
    arr = splitArrayForMergeSort(arr);
}
```

Comment: You don't follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which is a major reason for problems (since you pass and returns the arrays by value).

Comment: You can probably use [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) building block from the standard library, to save yourself few lines of code.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve] in the question itself (the entire question could be simplified to why doesn't `z` change in `int f (int a, int b, int c) {c = a + b; return c;} int main () {int x = 1, y = 2, z = 0; f (x, y, z);}`?) 2) `Array Array::merge(Array left, Array right, Array mergedArray)` You are passing the array by value (hence you are operating on the copy of the array), and you are ignoring the return value of the method.

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about `splitArrayForMergeSort()` not returning a value on all code paths.

Answer (score 0):

thanks i forgot to return `splitedArray` at the end of the method `splitArrayForMergeSort()`, after i added it , everything works,

Comment: With the code as you show in the link, it only *seems* to work! In reality you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).